# Add formula containing condition to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add following formula:

```
=IF(A1="string_condition";"variant1";"variant2")
```

to selected range of cells `(B1:B10)` using `VBA` this way:

```
Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=IF(A1=""string_condition"";""variant1"";""variant2"")"
```

but it doesn't work, it reports following message:

```
Runtime error 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

where is the problem? this testing formula (without strings) works normally:

```
Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=SUM(C1:C10)"
```

Comment: commas instead of semi-colons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA you don't use semi colons you use commas

```
Sub Main()
 Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=IF(A1=""yes"",""no"",""yes"")"
End Sub
```

Note: you wrap double quotes with an extra quote inside a string to escape it.